# RTL8188CUS Yosemite Drvier?

Tags: osx-yosemite

I'm trying to get the generic wifi adapter to work on Yosemite and days of Googling has left me with numerous downloaded drivers but nothing worked. I noticed that the wifi utility gets installed but thats it, the app crashes after reboot and when I uninstall it, I noticed that the Kext's doesn't exist. Any idea on how to get this fixed?

Comment: Possible uplicate of [Installing Generic USB Wifi Dongle to OSX](http://superuser.com/questions/848253/installing-generic-usb-wifi-dongle-to-osx).